# Query to get data in ascending interval format

Tags: sql, oracle

column in table: `interval varchar(12)`

when user enters data in this column like this:

```
1
10-20
3-5
5-3
25-34
20-25
2
4-8
```

and output should be like this:

```
1
2
3-5
4-8
9-10
10-20
20-25
25-34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  col
FROM
(
        SELECT '1' col  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '10-20'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '3-5'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '5-3'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '25-34'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '20-25'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '2'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT '4-8'    FROM DUAL
)
ORDER   BY
        TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1))
,       TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2))


1
2
3-5
4-8
5-3
10-20
20-25
25-34
```

Comment: but sir data is not static n we don't know in which format data is stored in database.

Comment: thanks sir it is working for me.after some edition.

Comment: @SNPrasadRao Bro! I am not "sir"! :-) What do you mean it is not static? What can be the format then?

Comment: I apply this:-
select * from Bank_1023 ORDER   BY  TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(INTERVAL, '\w+', 1, 1))
,       TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(INTERVAL, '\w+', 1, 2))

Comment: The select statement is not need. I am would be more interested in the values in table that it does not work for.